# Matching a string at the beginning of a inputstream

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I have implemented a simple inputstream manipulator to match the next n chars in an inputstream against a given string. However, I am not sure if this is the best way to do this. Any hints?

```
class MatchString {
private:
  std::string mString;

public:
  MatchString(const std::string &str) { 
    mString = str; 
  }

  std::istream& operator()(std::istream& is) const {
    // Allocate a string buffer, ...
    char *buffer = new char[mString.length()];

    // ... read next n chars into the buffer ...
    is.read(buffer, mString.length());

    // ... and compare them with given string.
    if(strncmp(buffer, mString.c_str(), mString.length())) {
      throw MismatchException(mString);
    }

    delete[] buffer;

    return is;
  }
};

inline MatchString match(const std::string &str) {
  return MatchString(str);
}

inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const MatchString& matchStr) {
  return matchStr(is);
}
```

**EDIT:**

A solution consuming the matched chars could be implemented based on the suggestion of user673679:

```
class MatchString {
  ... 

  std::istream& operator()(std::istream& is) const {
    // Match the next n chars.
    std::for_each(mString.begin(), mString.end(),
      [&](const char c) {
        if(is.get() != c) {
          throw MismatchException(mString);
        }
      });

    return is;
  }
};
```

How would I implement this if I don't want to consume the chars?

**EDIT II:**

Here another solution mentioned by fjardon:

```
class MatchString {
  ...

  std::istream& operator()(std::istream& is) const {
    // Match the next n chars.
    if(std::mismatch(mString.begin(), mString.end(), 
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is)).first != mString.end()) {
      throw MismatchException(mString);
    }

    return is;
  }
};
```

**EDIT III:**

Finally got a working function, that will revert consumption, if string doesn't match:

```
class MatchString {
  ...

  std::istream& operator()(std::istream& is) const {
    // Match the next n chars.
    std::streampos oldPos = is.tellg();
    if(std::mismatch(mString.begin(), mString.end(), 
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is)).first != mString.end()) {
      is.seekg(oldPos);
      throw MismatchException(mString);
    }

    return is;
  }
};
```

Comment: If you are looking for code review, you must post this on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why don't you replace this `char *buffer = new char[mString.length()]` with a `std::string` and avoid memory management?

Comment: Why dynamically allocate memory in your `operator()` function? Just create an empty `std::string` object of the length needed, and read into it. Then you can use the `==` operator to compare the strings.

Comment: Also, the function *consumes* the input it read, which might not always be wanted.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Is there a simple way to read a fixed number of characters into a `std::string`?

Comment: Strings (and vectors too) are basically wrappers around a contiguous slice of memory, in other words it wraps an array. So to get a pointer to the first entry (like what `buffer` in your code really is) you can use e.g. `&tempStr[0]`. It works because [`std::string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) returns a reference.

Comment: @Beta Yeah ther is a `std::copy_n` function, which you could use with a `std::istreambuf_iterator`.

Comment: With c++14 you could directly use [std::mismatch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) with an istreambuf_iterator and a string iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of allocating and copying the whole string from the stream, you could just check one character at a time and avoid allocating the buffer completely:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

auto mString = std::string("foobar");

std::istream& match(std::istream& is) {

    for (auto c : mString)
        if (c != is.get())
            throw std::runtime_error("nope");

    return is;
}

int main()
{
    auto input = "foobarbaz";

    auto stream = std::istringstream(input);

    match(stream);

    std::cout << "done!" << std::endl;
}
```

You should also add error checking for is.get() (or .read() in your original code).

Comment: I have updated my question, with a newer version based on you suggestions. However, as Joachim Pileborg pointed out, your solution would consume the characters.

Comment: LOL for throwing exception if it doesn't match

Comment: @BЈовић: What would you do on mismatch?

Comment: @Avedo For a start, it is wrong that such function doesn't return bool.

Comment: @BЈовић As this function is used as stream manipulator for input streams  (see question) it can't return bool. AFAIK stream manipulators have to return the stream itself. If you have a better solution, post it and I will accept it.